# Article class complaining about missing \title

Tags: titles, documentclass-writing

I'm making a custom Latex class which I am basing on the article class. When compiling a document I get `! LaTeX Error: No \title given.`, even though I use \title in the document.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We need to know your custom code for the class. Add a MWE and attach the `.cls`.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use `\maketitle` *before* using `\title` in your document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means `\@title` hadn't been defined by the time `\maketitle` is used.

So either you haven't used `\title` or used it in a local group, or redefined it not to define `\@title`.

Comment: I use `\@title` in the class to define a header for my class: how should I get at that information in a better way?

Comment: @adamse hard to say as you have not shown any code. But you can't use a command before it has been defined...

Comment: My solution: supply a command `\makeheadfoot` that creates the header.